# Vlookup on a column returns all row results

Tags: excel-formula

Looking to have a lookup result return the full row data EG

Date    | A | B | C |

1/1/19    C   D   F

1/1/19    A   D   G

2/1/19    F   W   B

Lookup - Date 1/1/19

Result should display:

1/1/19    C   D   F

1/1/19    A   D   G

Formulas found only return one cell worth of data. Can this be done?

Comment: How about do a filter for the Date column, or use a Pivot Table and put the date in Filters field and all others in the Rows field?

Comment: Please post sample snap (Screen shot) which is regarding to your question! So that it can be easily answered.

Comment: What have you tried? You will need a vlookup for each cell you want to return. Search as there are many examples of vlookup on here as well as questions about dealing with duplicates which you need.

Comment: Please post sample snap (Screen shot) which is regarding to your question! So that it can be easily answered.

Comment: Try a combination of index() and match() functions